# How to make Group By and sort in Python for mapreducer in hadoop

Tags: python, sorting, hadoop, group-by, mapreduce

I have a dataset with 100k rows with 17 cols.
I would like to know how to groupby and sort in hadoop mapreducer using python

here is my `mapper.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys


for line in sys.stdin:
    data = line.strip().split(",")
    if len(data) == 17:
        VendorID, tpep_pickup_datetime, tpep_dropoff_datetime, passenger_count, trip_distance, RatecodeID, store_and_fwd_flag, PULocationID, DOLocationID, payment_type, fare_amount, extra, mta_tax, tip_amount, tolls_amount, improvement_surcharge, total_amount = data
    print passenger_count,"\t",PULocationID,"\t", DOLocationID
```

my `reducer.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    data_mapped = line.strip().split("\t")
    if len(data_mapped) != 3:
        continue

    passenger_count, PULocationID, DOLocationID = data_mapped

    passenger_count = int(passenger_count)

    if passenger_count <2:
        print passenger_count,"\t", PULocationID, "\t", DOLocationID
```

to run mapreducer in hadoop I used this cmd
`hadoop jar /usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-streaming.jar -mapper mapper.py -reducer reducer.py -input /user/maria_dev/trim_table.csv -output /user/maria_dev/joboutput1 -file /root/mapper.py /root/reducer.py`

the output of my `joboutput`
    
    `1   161     142
    1   170     162
    1   233     248
    1   68      230
    1   237     237
    and so on with some duplication and unsorted.`

Hope someone could help me.
the output I wanted is 

`count|PULocationID|DOLocationID`

I wanted to sort by count desc